# homogeneous or non-homogeneous ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I've just gotten back a corrected homework about differential equations, and now I need your help:
Why is the ODE $u''(x)=u(x)\sqrt{x}$ homogeneous, but the PDE $u_{xx}(x,y)+u_{yy}(x,y)e^{\sin x}=1$ is inhomogeneous? In both cases we have a function of $x$ that is not related to $u$, namely $e^{\sin x}$ and $\sqrt{x}$, don't we? So I'd think that both are inhomogeneous.

What am I doing wrong here?

Cheers,
Marie :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't mix up notions of autonomous ODEs (where no direct instance of the independent variable can appear) and linear homogeneous equations. The equation
$$
u''(x) - u(x)\sqrt x = 0
$$
is homogeneous since the RHS is zero but not autonomous due to the term $\sqrt{x}.$ W.r.t. the PDE 
$$
u_{xx}+u_{yy} \mathrm e^{\sin x} = 1
$$ 
the RHS is non-zero, so the PDE is not homogeneous.

Some more examples:

1. homogeneous autonomous
   $$
   u'(x)+u(x) = 0.
   $$
2. homogeneous non-autonomous
   $$
   u''(x)+\color{red}{x}\cdot u(x)  = 0
   $$
3. non-homogeneous autonomous
   $$
   u'(x)-2u(x) = \color{red}{1}
   $$
4. non-homogeneous non-autonomous
   $$
   u''(x)+\color{red}{x}\cdot u'(x) = \color{red}{x^2+1}
   $$

where red color is used to highlight terms which bring "non" into the classification.

Comment: okay, the RHS is supposed to be $=1$, sorry!

Comment: @Marie.P.: ok, added to the answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: crystalclear! Awesome, thanks!